# XNA under the hood?

Tags: xna

From what I understand, the XNA framework is little more than a wrapper around DirectX with some helper classes.  I am interested in looking at this code though.  Is there anywhere that I can see some of the actual code that went into making this framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code belongs to Microsoft and isn't open source.  I don't think that Microsoft will be releasing the code for it in the near future.

However, there is an application called [`Reflector.Net`](http://www.reflector.net/).  This will allow you to view the code, but it will be obfuscated, but it may give you an idea of what is going on in the DLLs.

Comment: Ever since Redgate saw fit to remotely nuke the free version of Reflector, I've been recommending [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) as as an excellent and free alternative.

Comment: Thank you.  I somehow doubted it but you never know.  I will definitely check out Reflector.Net.  Or something of that type.